# Error using htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm using **`gargoylesoftware htmlunit`** in java to get webpages after their javascript has been run (as you can't do this with the inbuilt java libraries). I'm using this in a webscraper, so this code is being run many many times over without issue, however quite randomly I get this error every hour or so after running the program:

```
Jan 13, 2015 8:03:52 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole info
INFO: ThreadStats: couldn't get the catalog (undefined)
Jan 13, 2015 8:03:52 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole info
INFO: ThreadStats: couldn't get the catalog ()
```

The code this **error** is appearing on is:

```
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(URIget.getSearchURL(ToSearch, board));
```

I'm pretty sure the error doesn't originate from my URI.getSearchURL method, as it doesn't do anything fancy, only stick a few strings together

Comment: So you just don't want the message to appear? or you want to know why it is appearing?

Comment: @Arya Both if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting these after creating a WebClient and it should prevent the message from showing

```
            webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
            LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLDocument").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.WindowProxy").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: This may silence the error, but it won't keep it from happening and breaking my program.

Comment: @user3537381 I had no idea it actually breaks your program. You are right this only prevents it from being printed. Another solution would be to use try/catch to handle the error in a way that it won't stop your program and you can control what happens when the error happens.

Comment: At the moment I am using a try, catch solution, although it isn't really the best of solutions.